# WooCommerce custom report: Get orders with completed status

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, orders

im making a custom reports for woocommerce im trying to add a report for all delivered orders here is what im doing

```
        $orders = wc_get_orders( array('numberposts' => -1) );
    foreach( $orders as $order ){
    if ( $order->get_status() === completed){
        $order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_name = $item->get_name();
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        }
        $orders_completed .=  '<tr><td>' . $order->get_order_number() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_date_created()->date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_status() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_total() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $product_id . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $product_name . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_item_count() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_billing_first_name() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_billing_email() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order->get_billing_phone() . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method_title'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

i get

> Call to undefined method WC_Admin_Order_Refund::get_order_number()

i don't know what im doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target only **"shop_order"** post type, **without "shop_order_refund"** post type in your `WC_Order_Query`, because some `WC_Order` methods doesn't exist for `WC_Order_Refund`.

So you can replace instead the first line of your code by:

```
$orders = wc_get_orders( array('limit' => -1, 'type' => 'shop_order') );
```

This should solve this issue.

See [the official documentation about `wc_get_orders` and `WC_Order_Query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query)

Comment: i was hopping that you are online :D 
as always problem solved thank you so much